# What is __declspec and when do I need to use it?

Tags: c++

I have seen instances of `__declspec` in the code that I am reading. What is it? And when would I need to use this construct?

Comment: If you were unlucky and moved from Linux to Windows, you might waste time trying to figure out why your DLLs wouldn't work, until you find that you have to add `__declspec(dllexport)` before each function in your library

Answer (score 103, accepted):

This is a Microsoft specific extension to the C++ language which allows you to attribute a type or function with storage class information.

Documentation

[__declspec (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/declspec)

Comment: Thanks - but what would I use it for?

Comment: For declaring COM interfaces and classes, for example, you use __declspec(uuid), for exporting functions sans a DEF file you use __declspec(dllexport), etc. The full list is quite long.

Comment: @ScottJ I constantly use it for properties: __declspec(property(get=X put=X)) data-type identifier. MSDN has more details of course.

As a "C# to C/C++ programmer" it's a bliss!

Answer (score 70):

The canonical examples are `__declspec(dllimport)` and `__declspec(dllexport)`, which instruct the linker to import and export (respectively) a symbol from or to a DLL.

```
// header
__declspec(dllimport) void foo();


// code - this calls foo() somewhere in a DLL
foo();
```

(`__declspec(..)` just wraps up Microsoft's specific stuff - to achieve compatibility, one would usually wrap it away with macros)

Comment: @tetris, you don't know from the code. The decision is made by the linker, who will pick the first `.lib` it finds that has a matching exported symbol.

Answer (score 28):

It is mostly used for importing symbols from / exporting symbols to a shared library (DLL). Both Visual C++ and GCC compilers support `__declspec(dllimport)` and `__declspec(dllexport)`. Other uses (some Microsoft-only) are documented [in the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dabb5z75(v=vs.140).aspx).

Answer (score 16):

Another example to illustrate the **__declspec** keyword:

When you are writing a Windows Kernel Driver, sometimes you want to write your own prolog/epilog code sequences **using inline assembler code**, so you could declare your function with the **naked** attribute.

```
__declspec( naked ) int func( formal_parameters ) {}
```

Or

```
#define Naked __declspec( naked )
Naked int func( formal_parameters ) {}
```

Please refer to [naked (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5w10wxs(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 9):

Essentially, it's the way Microsoft introduces its C++ extensions so that they won't conflict with future extensions of standard C++. With __declspec, you can attribute a function or class; the exact meaning varies depending on the nature of __declspec. __declspec(naked), for example, suppresses prolog/epilog generation (for interrupt handlers, embeddable code, etc), __declspec(thread) makes a variable thread-local, and so on.

The full list of __declspec attributes is available on MSDN, and varies by compiler version and platform.

Comment: Considering non-microsoft compilers like `GCC 4.2`, that offer alternative in addition to their `__attribute__ ((dllexport))` to `__declspec(dllexport)`, is it fair to call `__declspec`, a Microsoft-only extension?

Comment: I don't know of any other compilers that would support it, so yes, it's Microsoft only.

Comment: Borland's C++Builder also uses __declspec.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been eight years but I wanted to share this piece of code found in MRuby that shows how `__declspec()` can bee used at the same level as the `export keyword`.

```
/** Declare a public MRuby API function. */
#if defined(MRB_BUILD_AS_DLL)
#if defined(MRB_CORE) || defined(MRB_LIB)
# define MRB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
# define MRB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#else
# define MRB_API extern
#endif
```