# C++ Declspec align

Tags: c++, structure, alignment

Hi am new to Visual C++, Could Someone please explain what **ConfParams()** declared in a structure does

```
__declspec(align(BYTE)) struct ConfParams
{
    BOOL m_timeout;
    DOUBLE m_caution;
    ConfParams();      
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could Someone please explain what ConfParams() declared in a structure does

It's a constructor declaration.

In C++ other than default accessibility level `struct` and `class` are equivalent.   `struct` by default has `public` members, `class` by default has `private` members.

---

I'm not clear why your subject references `__declspec` but if that's what you want to know about [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284610/what-is-declspec-and-when-do-i-need-to-use-it).

Member functions have no alignment only the data is affected.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused in seeing a constructor being defined in a struct. Wasn't quite sure if it had something to do with __declspec.

Answer (score 1):

google says

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/83ythb65%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

"Use __declspec(align(#)) to precisely control the alignment of user-defined data (for example, static allocations or automatic data in a function)"

It will make the compiler start every instance on a byte boundary. Without it instances would have been aligned on the machines natural boundary - which would probably be 4 bytes.