# multiple definition of `imp_ZTVN4Rcpp14not_compatibleE` on WindowsXP with RInside

Tags: c++, windows, r, rcpp, rinside

The software I am talking of contains 5 files and compiles "perfectly fine" on `openSUSE 11.3` with `gcc-4.5.1`:

The same software shows the following error on `Windows XP` with `Mingw (gcc-4.6.3)`.

**UPDATE**

The problem is discovered.

The problem is w.r.t the R's function `parseEval`.
There are two similar functions: `parseEval` and `parseEvalQ`.
The former returns a value, and the other returns void.

I have used `parseEval` in a C++ plus Qt project, and it works very fine on Linux, and throws the above shown error on Windows.

**Here is the reproducible example:**

demo.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <RInside.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

RInside R (0, NULL);
RInside & qtToR (R);

int main ()
{
    int numberOne = 1;
    int numberTwo = 2;

    qtToR ["numberOne"] = numberOne;
    qtToR ["numberTwo"] = numberTwo;

    R.parseEvalQ ("sum = numberOne + numberTwo;");

    int returnValue = R.parseEval ("sum");
    std :: cout << "\n" << returnValue << "\n";
}
```

Corresponding .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE    = app
TARGET      =
DEPENDPATH  += .

SOURCES     += demo.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += c:/R-2.15.1/include
INCLUDEPATH += c:/R-2.15.1/library/Rcpp/include
INCLUDEPATH += c:/R-2.15.1/library/RInside/include

LIBS        += -Lc:/R-2.15.1/bin/i386 -lR
LIBS        += -Lc:/R-2.15.1/library/Rcpp/libs/i386 -lRcpp
LIBS        += -Lc:/R-2.15.1/library/RInside/libs/i386 -lRInside

# You'll keep pulling your hair if you miss this statement when you are on windows.
CONFIG      += console
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give us a bit more information? File structure, if you've tried anything to troubleshoot etc?

Comment: I can provide the .pro file, if that's what you want? What else info did you mean? @Fabian

Comment: You are using different versions of GCC under different platforms with different builds of Qt. Of course this _may_ happen. It's hard to say without further information (i.e. code), though.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I do understand that, but the code is in 5 files interdependent on each other. Not sure how should I produce the code here. :(

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall See the pro file please.

Comment: Show also the relevant C++ code

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Alright, I'll post two .cpp and .h files, out of the five which I think are relevant..

Comment: ***I have already mailed this to `rcpp-devel`.*** My mail is  awaiting moderation there.

Comment: Previously I didn't know that was related to R hence didn't tag it as R.

Comment: Briefly: a) rcpp-devel is a subscriber-only list, and I will not manually moderate you or anybody else.  Subscribe, or be ignored. b) This is obviously a linker issue with a problem you have in your toolchain.  See all the previous answers to all your previous (near identical) questions.  I recommend the .pro file I post, and make sure you *use the same gcc version for Qt and R*.  c) I just deleted your post as it had a >200kb attachment. What on Earth were you thinking?  There is a default 40kb limit.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I "did" subscribe to that list, that's why I could send the mail. The reason of the attachment is that the text on windows terminal cannot be selected by mouse. Therefore I had no choice other than posting the png to show the full compilation message. You said: *" I recommend the .pro file I post,"* If you mean the QtDensity pro file for Windows, then I have tried it many times, it does not work directly on Windows. And yes, gcc version for Qt and R "are" same in my case. I have manually installed the required mingw version for Qt.

Comment: I am not going to explain to you how to use a Windows computer but try right-clicking the title bar and follow edit. As for your issues, I suspect they are home grown as I and other had luck building Qt and R apps the way it is recommended and documented in the respective Qt and R documentation. You are free to continue to do things your way, but it may also continue to not work that way. And as I must have said a dozen times now: _post on the list_ where you find other R + Qt + RInside users which you _do not find here_.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel You said: **"As for your issues, I suspect they are home grown "**. I agree. Today I again compiled the above reproducible program with the standard "makefile" of R for windows. It "did" compile properly. So, this proves that the fault is with my .pro file, again. This time I couldn't doubt my pro file because the problem occurs ONLY with the function `parseEval`. Once I comment out that particular function, whole project (including many other functions of R) compiles fine. Again, please pardon my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I said:

> > This is solved. The problem was NOT related to the .pro file, it was related to the syntax of `parseEval` function. The RInside I have on
> >     Linux is older than RInside I have on Windows. The versions of Rcpp
> >     installed are also different on my Linux system and Windows system.
>
> This syntax of `parseEval` -    `int returnValue = R.parseEval
>   ("sum");`   works fine on Linux with older RInside but fails on
>   Windows with newer RInside.
>
> So, I modified the above code as follows and it compiled successfully
>   with the above .pro file.
>
> `SEXP ans;`   `int returnValue = R.parseEval ("sum", ans);`

This did compile successfully, but to my horror this joy was just the calmness before the storm!
*The same error had now shifted to the run time!*

So, the permanent solution to this error is editing the .pro file and linking **Rcpp** AFTER **RInside**:

`LIBS        += -Lc:/R-2.15.1/library/RInside/libs/i386 -lRInside`
`LIBS        += -Lc:/R-2.15.1/library/Rcpp/libs/i386 -lRcpp`

Answer (score 1):

Linking semantics is different in Linux and in Windows, notably for dynamic libraries.

I suggest to read [Levine's *linkers and loaders*](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) book.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2284610/841108), and look for [Gcc function attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html), `dllexport` and `dllimport`.

With Qt, you may need to use [Q_DECL_EXPORT](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#Q_DECL_EXPORT) etc.... (This Qt macro will work both on Linux and on Windows).

Comment: I have added the pro file, see if that helps. :( Thanks for the link though.

Comment: I believe the **issues are inside *your* source code**, not inside your `.pro` project file. You need to use `Q_DECL_EXPORT` and `Q_DECL_IMPORT` (specially if you are making a shared library, see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sharedlibrary.html etc).

Comment: Basile, I have added the header of two files. Please tell me if you need more.

Comment: I think you should use the `Q_DECL_EXPORT` appropriately. Where are you using it??

Comment: I think I have found the problem. I'll post it when I go to office. Then you can tell me whether it is related to this or not. :) Thanks for trying to help.