# weird c function syntax

Tags: c, linux, windows, syntax

I know my C up to this point. I was looking at the source files of PHP I downloaded, and I saw this strange syntax:

```
PHPAPI int php_printf(const char *format, ...)
{
    // code...
}
```

What does the `PHPAPI` do before the return type `int`? I've tried searching all over and I can't understand what this means. Is it a second return type? It can't be because the function does return an int. Maybe it extends to some other struct declared in a header file?

Comment: Most probably it specifies the calling convention.

Comment: PHPAPI is probably a #define in one of the include files.

Comment: If you can pre-process the file then you can understand what the PHPAPI means

Comment: cc (or gcc) with the `-E` will show you the source file after the pre-processor has chewed on it. This is a quick (if verbose) way to find out what the macro expands to.

Comment: You can search the PHP-Source code on GitHub: https://github.com/search?q=%22define+PHPAPI%22+%40php+repo%3Aphp%2Fphp-src&type=Code&ref=searchresults

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The hard way:

Go to the makefile and add in the line that compiles the sources: `-E`, by doing so you will see the source cose after the preprocessing phase.

### The easy way:

Search all the project for `PHPAPI`:

find it in [php.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-4.3/php/main/php.h):

```
#ifdef PHP_WIN32
#include "win95nt.h"
#   ifdef PHP_EXPORTS
#   define PHPAPI __declspec(dllexport) 
#   else
#   define PHPAPI __declspec(dllimport) 
#   endif
#define PHP_DIR_SEPARATOR '\\'
#else
#define PHPAPI
#define THREAD_LS
#define PHP_DIR_SEPARATOR '/'
#endif
```

Now what you need to know is what is `__declspec(dllexport)` and what is `__declspec(dllimport)`

In the SO thread- [What is __declspec and when do I need to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284610/what-is-declspec-and-when-do-i-need-to-use-it)

see [Alexander Gessler answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2284630/1031417):

> The canonical examples are `__declspec(dllimport)` and
>   `__declspec(dllexport)`, which instruct the linker to import and
>   export (respectively) a symbol from or to a DLL.
>
> ```
> // header
> __declspec(dllimport) void foo();
>
>
> // code - this calls foo() somewhere in a DLL
> foo();
> ```
>
> (`__declspec(..)` just wraps up Microsoft's specific stuff - to
>   achieve compatibility, one would usually wrap it away with macros)