How to properly use c++ header files across projects
Say I have two projects, one that is sort of like an 'application engine' and one that is the actual application. The engine takes care of things like window management, and I should be able to switch out the window library it uses without affecting the application, so application has to not include anything related to the window library.
I build application engine to a .dll and put it in the same folder as the application.exe.
In the engine project I have a window wrapper class whose header file (windowWrapper.h) looks like
#include <windowLibrary.h>

class WindowWrapper
{
    private:
    Window* window

    // ...

};

and in the application project I have an application class whose header file (application.h) looks like
#include <windowWrapper.h>

class Application
{

    private:
    WindowWrapper window;

    // ...

};

This theoretically works like I want, but I get an error (header not found) because application.h is indirectly including windowLibrary.h, but windowLibrary.h is not in the include directories for the application. (It's in an include directory for the DLL.) If I try and move #include <windowLibrary.h> to windowWrapper.cpp, I can no longer have the Window* window pointer in the WindowWrapper class.
What do I do?
So far I have tended to put all includes and declarations in header files and all definitions in .cpp files, almost without exception - is this wrong?

As you use a pointer to Window you might want to use a forward declaration without including windowLibrary.h in the header. I.e. class Window; before class Application {... declaration.

@vahancho And also include windowLibrary.h in windowWrapper.cpp? All the red lines go away but I still get a bunch of compile errors

You could try to use static linking instead of dynamic linking since both applications are written by yourself. This gives the compiler and linker more oppertunity to optimise as well. Though this is unrelated to your issue; Using DLL on windows might cause linking errors (idk your setup) but perhaps you could look into: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284610/what-is-declspec-and-when-do-i-need-to-use-it

You could use interfaces for this though. Thats what they are for.

Do you want to “switch out the window library” without recompiling?

"I get an error because application.h is indirectly including windowLibrary.h which it knows nothing about."
If it is including windowLibrary.h, indirectly or directly, then it knows everything in windowLibrary.h.
Certainly that defeats the apparent purpose of class WindowWrapper but there is no inherent reason for it cause an error. What error?
You need to post a Minimal Reproducible Example
demonstrating the error, which for all we know may be quite unrelated to your design problem.

@DavisHerring no I want to switch out window library without having to refactor the application project

@MikeKinghan The error comes from not adding windowLibrary.h's directory to the include directories of the application project - I want to only add windowLibrary.h's directory to the include directories of the application engine project, so that application can stay agnostic

@Amparo I am not sure what an interface is in c++?

@Depenau In c++ an interface is a pure abstract class with only virtual functions that are set to zero; virtual void function() = 0; This tells the compiler not to compile them, but just aknowledge its existance so you can use the function-calls wherever needed. I think you are looking for a dependency injection technique, so Interfaces are perfect for this. If thats not the case, I must have misunderstood your question.

@Amparo no that sounds like what I am looking for - I will have to read up on c++ interfaces. Thanks!

@Depenau "The error comes from not adding windowLibrary.h's directory to the include directories of the application project" -- Information like this should be in the question, not buried in comments (that are temporary notes). I'll give it a shot, but you should correct anything I misunderstood.
